# Error al Modificar atributo de un objeto incluido en una arrayList. Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist

os agradezco si me podéis dar una pista para desatascar que ya llevo unos cuantos días dándole vueltas.

tengo las siguientes clases:

**Asignaciones{}**  que contiene 
      ArrayList de objetos 'AsignacionTrabajos' llamado *asignaciones*;

y los métodos

```java
public AsignacionTrabajos getAsigTrabajo(int IdAsignacion) {}
public void setAsigTrabajo(AsignacionTrabajos aT) {}
```

**AsignacionTrabajos{}** que contiene el atributo `estadoAsignacion` (tipo enum) y el método

```
public void setEstadoAsignacion(int nuevoEstado) {}
```

**MenuPrincipal{}** con la orden

```
asignaciones.setAsigTrabajo(asignaciones.getAsigTrabajo(iDAsignacion).setEstadoAsignacion(nEA))
```

nEA es un int, igualmente lo probé pasándole el tipo enum modificando adecuadamente el código en los métodos de las clases correspondientes.

lo haga como lo haga aparece el mismo error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como debería hacerlo para modificar el valor del atributo usando un comando de este estilo o similar?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres hace encadenación de métodos deberías devolver la referencia al `this` en el método `setAsigTrabajo` y que no fuera de tipo `void`.

Pero puedes hacerlo

```java
asignaciones.setAsigTrabajo(asignaciones.getAsigTrabajo(iDAsignacion));
asignaciones.setEstadoAsignacion(nEA));
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN DE LA RESPUESTA** (tal como pone en los comentarios interpreté mal el código que había publicado el OP).

Como ya tienes un metodo que te devuelve la asignación de trabajo que quieres asignar puedes guardar la `AsignacionTrabajos` en una variable local y cambiar su estado. Como ya tienes la referencia al trabajo que quieres asignar puedes pasarla como parámetro al método `asignaciones.setAsigTrabajo`.

```java
AsignacionTrabajos asginacionTrabajo = asignaciones.getAsigTrabajo(iDAsignacion);
asginacionTrabajo.setEstadoAsignacion(nEA));
asignaciones.setAsigTrabajo(asignacionTrabajo);
```

Comment: Gracias ajuni880, pero creo que no entiendo del todo tu respuesta seguro por mi falta de conocimiento. setAsigTrabajo es void porque es el metodo que modifica un objeto en el arraylist asignaciones y al ser un setter es por eso que es un void. En el caso de setEstadoAsignacion(nEA) es un metodo del objeto AsignacionTrabajos, por ello entiendo que no funcionaría al poner asignaciones.setEstadoAsignacion(...) Te agradezco mucho si me puedes aclarar. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: perdon leí mal el código, tienes razón. Pensé que el `setEstadoAsignacion` era un metodo de la clase `Asignaciones` pero no pertenece `AsignacionTrabajos`. Actualizo mi respuesta.